# не помещается выпадающее меню(вложенный список) на экране что делать?

Tags: css

Это из за того что блок sticky имеет

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div id="sticky" class="site-header sticky">
  <ul>
    <li id="categories">
      <a href="">Каталог</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Подкатегория</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">N-количество</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А где выпадающее меню то? Пока видим только вложенные списки.

Comment: ну вложенного списка это и есть меню

Comment: сделайте `css бургер меню` https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp